# Does creating a new object unbinds my variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I'm creating this component in my angular application and I'm binding an object :

### Component.js

```
angular.module("app").component( "component", {
    controller: function() {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.createInstance = function() {
            ctrl.binding = new Object();
        }
    },
    bindings: {
        binding: "="
    },
    templateUrl: "component.html"
});
```

### App.html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Object.items">
    <component binding="item"></component>
</div>
```

If I were to execute `createInstance()` in my component would it unbind the object?
If so, how would I keep the binding while creating a new instance of an object?

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling, I found out that it does change the reference to the object. A workaround would be to use `angular.copy()`.

```
ctrl.createInstance = function() {
    angular.copy(ctrl.binding, new Object());
}
```